# Static Html pages with same header / footer included

Tags: html, css, templates, static

I want to generate my webpages with some content for Header / footer taken from a single file.

I've no Server side support and I'd like to avoid iframes, javascript, css tricks to solve this problem

I would simply need a kind of software template where I can 'compile' my static html pages before uploading them via ftp

Is there something like this? How are you solving the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `I'd like to avoid iframes, javascript, css` regardless of *iframes*.. Do you want to rely on user agent stylesheet for your webpages?

Comment: I mean I'd like to avoid all 3 as a solution for including a common header in all my pages. I don't want to use ajax, iframes or other tricks.

Comment: If you're looking for [HTML template engines](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+template+engines), you might want to take a look at: [Liquid HTML](http://liquidmarkup.org/), [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/), [HAML](http://haml.info/), [Slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a whole slew of software that should cater your needs. *static site generator* should be a good search string on google. my personal preference would be the ruby based  [nanoc](http://nanoc.ws/) but many others exist. [Assemble](https://github.com/assemble/generator-assemble) also looks very nice and features a yeoman generator.

Comment: nanoc looks really nice. also the support for multi-language with the subfoder solution is great from a SEO prospective! thanks a lot for this

Comment: http://jekyllrb.com/ is also pretty nice

Comment: yea, jekyll is nice! out of interest, which one did you choose in the end?

Comment: I went for Jekyll. I like the way it integrates with Github pages. I can host my site for free and have it version controlled at the same time. The only downside is that on Github you can't enable additional plugins. So if for example you need to use a multilanguage jekyll plugin you need then to precompile the site before putting it under Github and you loose the jekyll support Github side. Apart from that it works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you make php files with the `include` procedure to include the header and footer content and then run them using the `php` command it will output the html to stdout

Comment: php is still a server-side solution

Comment: No you could run it on the client and save the output like i said in the answer

Answer (score 0):

use  iframe tag . search JQuery plugins for iframe such as http://jframe.co.uk/ 
 or you can use javascript template engine . for example https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

**Update 1** : 
you can put static parts of your page such as header and footer in template and on load page render it on some tag in body .

or 
 simply save HTML code of header in variable  in js file. and at onload set header inner HTML . 
  
page 1

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="layout.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">page 1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

page 2

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="layout.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
    page 2
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

layout.js

```
   function  mylayout(){
    var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];
    var s = '<li>text</li>';

    var header_div = document.createElement('div');
    header_div.innerHTML  = "<p> this is <b style=\"color: blue\"> header</b><br><a href=\"page1.htm\">page1</a> <a href=\"page2.htm\">page2</a></p>";

    var footer_div = document.createElement('div');
    footer_div.innerHTML  = "<p> this is <b style=\"color: red\"> footer</b></p>";

    if (_body.firstChild){
        _body.insertBefore(header_div, _body.firstChild);
    }else{
        _body.appendChild(header_div);
    }

    _body.appendChild(footer_div);
}

window.onload = function() {
    mylayout();
};
```

Comment: as mentioned I'd like to avoid iframes as a solution

Answer (score 0):

MovableType has a static file publishing mode

Comment: Good news, but shouldn't it be a comment?

Comment: No. On Stack Overflow most proposed answers are posted as answers rather than comments.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use a program from Microsoft called Expression Studio 4.  It allows me to create website templates with a header, footer and other stuff I know that will be static.

I think this is what you want. [Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Bv6Ik5exP8)  Because you want to create it before you upload it to the web server.

Comment: Could you add some code because if you give reference to link then it may be deleted in future and then your answer will be useless.